# Bad example in the Oracle's docs

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, interface, language-concepts

I read [this Oracle's article](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/usinginterface.html) about Interfaces in Java. I think, that the provided example is bad. They use the following example:

```
public interface Relatable {
  public int isLargerThan(Relatable other);
}

public class RectanglePlus implements Relatable {
  public int isLargerThan(Relatable other) {
    RectanglePlus otherRect = (RectanglePlus) other;
    if (this.getArea() < otherRect.getArea()) {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (this.getArea() > otherRect.getArea()) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;    
    }           
}
```

Is it acceptable to cast `Relatable other` to `RectanglePlus`? I think, not. In my understanding, such implementation will fails in case if this class will be used via interface reference, and someone will try to compare it with another implementation of `Relatable`, that isnt' actually an instance of `RectanglePlus`. And I think, that such usage of interfaces is valid, while the problem is in the implementation.

What do you think? May be I don't understand something?

Comment: Your concern is right but It is just an example. It is not complete code!

Answer (score 0):

You're right. This code might throw a cast exception if `isLargerThan` is given a `Relatable` that isn't an instance of `RectanglePlus` (or any of its children)

They should have checked the Class of the object passed using `instanceof`.